# bat file to move files in sub-folder to current folder

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, move

I am looking for a .bat file that will move all FILES inside subfolders to the parent folder.

Example:
C:/games/nintendo/N/gamename/gamename.iso

I want to run a file that will move that gamename.iso to the folder N to be:

C:/games/nintendo/N//gamename.iso

Thanks so much for the help :_)

Comment: Searching online... but nothing that does what I need :( I have no clue about code so I thought I would ask here to the people who actually know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set root_folder=C:\games

for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%G in ('dir %root_folder% /b /o:-n /s ^| findstr /i ".iso" ') do (
    move /y "%%G" "%%~dpG..\%%~nxG"
)
```

Update

Here is the explanation:
`set root_folder=C:\games` - We're setting a variable that we're going to use later; This is the root folder that we want to start scanning

`for /f` - you can get documentation on usage, by typing `for /?` in the command prompt OR this [LINK](http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm)

`dir %root_folder% /b /o:-n /s` - we're listing all the file/folders and sub-folders by using `/b` for bare format; `/o:-n` for descending sort order; `/s` for recursively walking down the folder structure

`^| findstr /i ".iso"` - we're piping `|` all that information through and then looking for things that contain `.iso` in the name.  Please note that and escape character `^` is required

`do (` - for every instance that give output in this operation do the following:

`move /y` - move and overwrite `/y` if necessary:

`%%G` - string that is the output from the criteria uptop.

`%%~dpG` - `d = drive letter`, `p = path` of the output string

`..` - this is the folder above the current folder

`\%%~nxG` - `n = filename`, `x = extension` for the file that matches the output.

Here is what it would look like expanded (therefore copying the file to `C:\games\nintendo\N\`:

```
move /y "C:\games\nintendo\N\gamename\gamename.iso" "C:\games\nintendo\N\gamename\..\\gamename.iso"
```

Comment: Please try to explain a bit more about how and why this works

Answer (score 0):

Create a bat file with the following:

xcopy C:/games/nintendo/N/gamename C:/games/nintendo/N  /s /e